# iOS: Improving speed of image drawing

Tags: ios, calayer, quartz-graphics, cgcontext

I have a sequence of images that I want to animate  (`UIImageView` supports some basic animation but it's not sufficient for my needs).

My first approach was to use `UIImageView` and set the `image` property when the image. This was too slow. The reason for the poor speed was due to the drawing of the images (which surprised me; I assumed the bottle neck would be loading the image).

My second approach was to use a generic `UIView` and set `view.layer.contents = image.CGImage`. This gave no noticeable improvement.

Both of these approaches must be performed on the main thread. I think the poor speed is due to having to draw the image data to a `CGContext`.

How can I improve the drawing speed? Is it possible draw to the context on a background thread?

Answer (score 9):

I managed to improve performance by doing a few things:

- I fixed my build process so that the PNGs were being iOS optimized. (The content for the app is being managed in a separate project which outputs a bundle. The default bundle settings are for an OS X bundle, which does not optimize PNGs).
- On a background thread I:

  1. Created a new bitmap context (code below)
  2. Drew the PNG image into the bitmap context
  3. Created a CGImageRef from the bitmap context
  4. Set `layer.content` on the main thread to the CGImageRef
- Used an `NSOperationQueue` to manage the operations.

I'm sure there's a better way of doing this, but the above results in acceptable performance.

```
-(CGImageRef)newCGImageRenderedInBitmapContext //this is a category on UIImage
{
    //bitmap context properties
    CGSize size = self.size;
    NSUInteger bytesPerPixel = 4;
    NSUInteger bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * size.width;
    NSUInteger bitsPerComponent = 8;

    //create bitmap context
    unsigned char *rawData = malloc(size.height * size.width * 4);
    memset(rawData, 0, size.height * size.width * 4);    
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();    
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(rawData, size.width, size.height, bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);

    //draw image into bitmap context
    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height), self.CGImage);
    CGImageRef renderedImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);

    //tidy up
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);    
    CGContextRelease(context);
    free(rawData);

    //done!
    //Note that we're not returning an autoreleased ref and that the method name reflects this by using 'new' as a prefix
    return renderedImage;
}
```

Comment: You may pass null to CGBitmapContextCreate as first argument. It will handle memory handling for you. Also, you must ALWAYS check the return value of malloc for possible failure.

Answer (score 0):

What is it about your animation requirements that make using UIImageView's built-in animation service using an array of UIImages * (animationImages) and accompanying animationDuration and animationRepeatCount not work?

If you are rapidly drawing multiple images, look closely at Quartz 2D.  If you are drawing , then animating (moving, zooming, etc) an image, you should be looking at Core Animation.

It sounds like Quartz 2D is what you want.  Apple docs here:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: `UIImageView` isn't sufficient because I require more control over the animation sequence. For example, looping frames 1-10, then playing frames 11-20, then looping frames 21-30.

Comment: Why not break each of those out into separate UIImageViews?