# How to increase speed when drawing an UIImage

Tags: ios, xcode

I am drawing images which are greater than 5mb inside a for-loop. I want to speed up processing. Any idea how to speed up ?

This is my code

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < 4; i++) {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imgSize, NO, 1);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, imgSize.width, imgSize.height)];
    newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
```

any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6708200/ios-improving-speed-of-image-drawing

Comment: Use an image view if possible. Hardware accelerated.

Comment: duci9y,
I sent the image from imageView, then I resize that image into 4 sizes. then I show action sheet with that 4 sizes. for an example IOS standard mail app. when you attach image. but the problem is it will take too much time.

Comment: What will take too much time? To reply directly to a user, prefix their name with an @ sign. For example, "@duci9y <your comment>."

Comment: @duci9y 
for draw image for given 4 sizes.

Comment: Just use the same image in four differently sized image views.

Comment: @duci9y The proceeder goes like this. I pick an image from gallery. then I convert it to UIImage. then I send that image to convert for 4 sizes. when it completed I show an action sheet. I can't use image views. any idea how to improve performance without using image views

Comment: I cannot understand you. Still, you can't go faster than what you're currently using. Maybe if you use Metal or OpenGL ES, but this is the fastest you can go. Try drawing each image on a different thread and see if that's any faster.